# parsing jsonp with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

I receive the folowing jsonp through a jQuery call :

```
DisplayDates({"dates":[ "10\/2012","9\/2012"]})
```

when I try display to the array in Firefox / Chrome, 'dates' only has 1 item "9/2012".

I have no clue why. I suppose the json is not properly formated but what should it be ?

My test code is :

```
function DisplayDates(data) {
    console.log(data);
}

$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://url?alf_callback=DisplayDates',
        dataType: 'jsonp'
    });
});
```

EDIT:
 I added other items and they appear. The only item not appearing is `"10\/2012"`. Why ?

Comment: DisplayDates is working, How are you displaying ?

Comment: yes DisplayDates is working. Firebug tells me there's only one item in 'dates'. Same result if I go through the data with a for.

Comment: Firebug is displaying 2 items for me.

Comment: yes but why is it not working with $.ajax then ?

Comment: my chromium console says 2 elements (tested with $.ajax jsonp and apache server)

Comment: tested in firefox/firebug too, it works as expected

Answer (score 0):

I was being a total idiot... my page and the other call weren't querying the same exact url (on guid in parameters changed slightly) and i didn't see it....
Thanks for all your testing